# Logging long tensor values in tensorflow estimator

Tags: python, tensorflow, logging, tensorflow-estimator

I have built a classification model using tensorflow estimator API. I am trying to get tensor outputs from hidden layes printed in logs while prediction using below code.

```
model = tf.estimator.DNNLinearCombinedClassifier(
        model_dir=model_dir,
        linear_feature_columns=wide_columns,
        dnn_feature_columns=deep_columns,
        dnn_hidden_units=hidden_units,
        config=run_config)
tensors_to_log = {"DenseOut": "dnn/logits/BiasAdd"}
logging_hook = tf.train.LoggingTensorHook(tensors=tensors_to_log, every_n_iter=1)
predictions = model.predict(train_input_fn, hooks=[logging_hook])
```

When i run the code I am able to get the tensors logged in output but since the value is very long it is truncated and i can only see few numbers in begining and end.

```
INFO:tensorflow:DenseOut = [[ 0.61572325 -0.44044942 -0.19232166 ...  0.04 0.605 0.15]]
```

How can I specify tensorflow to log the complete output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So interesting, I found that the solution was to set `np.set_printoptions`.

```
import numpy as np

np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.nan)
```

It seems that `tensorflow` and `numpy` are closely integrated.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Makes sense as tensors are also based on top of numpy array. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    import sys
    import numpy as np
    np.set_printoptions(threshold= sys.maxsize)
```